# android exoplayer pause video as well as audio

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-tv, exoplayer2.x

I am streaming the video off an `m3u8` file with exoplayer. When I click the Pause button in its default media control UI, or do `player.setPlayWhenReady(false)`, or do `player.seekTo`, the video pauses or goes to wherever it needs to perfectly fine, but the audio keeps playing regardless of what I do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friend please test this fun,

```
fun playOrPauseWhenReady(playing:Boolean){
   player.setPlayWhenReady(playing)
   player.getPlaybackState()
}
```

and you can call this fun every time you need